# Flutter error: misssing implementation of StatefulWidget.createState

Tags: flutter, function, dart, widget, state

```
import "package:flutter/material.dart";

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> creteState() {
    return MyAppState();
  }
}

class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  var questionIndex = 0;

  void AnswerQuestion() {
    setState(() {
      questionIndex = questionIndex + 1;
    });
    print(questionIndex);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var questions = [
      "whats your favorite color",
      "whats your favorite animal",
    ];
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('my first app'),
        ),
        body: Column(children: [
          Text(questions[questionIndex]),
          ElevatedButton(child: Text('answer1'), onPressed: AnswerQuestion),
          ElevatedButton(
              child: Text('answer2'),
              onPressed: () => print("answer 2 choosen")),
          ElevatedButton(child: Text('answer3'), onPressed: AnswerQuestion),
        ]),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

when running this app I get the error: misssing implementation of StatefulWidget.createState dart(non abstract class inherits abstract member) try implementing the missing method or make the class abstract

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't spell `createState` right. It should be `createState` instead of `creteState`

Comment: Please don't post answers only pointing out a typographical issue or a missing character. Such answers are unlikely to help future visitors since they are specific to OP's code. Instead, flag or vote to close the question as off-topic as per the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).